# how to set default answer to y in dos batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I try to write a batch file to use Gpg4win to encrypt file. 
here is what inside the batch file:

```
gpg2 --recipient client_certiticate_name -e test.txt
```

because of client certificate problem, I get following message:

"It is NOT certain that the key belongs to the person named
in the user ID.  If you *really* know what you are doing,
you may answer the next question with yes.
Use this key anyway? (y/N)"

So, I have to enter y all the time. There is any way I can put the answer in the batch file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

put the answers in a text file named a.txt and run your bat like this:

xxx.bat < a.txt

Answer (score 0):

Piping the Y into the command usually works. Though some executables clear the input buffer before asking for input.

```
echo Y|gpg2 --recipient client_certiticate_name -e test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a private key and certify the client certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Try encrypting with one of these

```
gpg2 --recipient client_certiticate_name -e -yes test.txt
```

or

```
gpg2 --recipient client_certiticate_name -e -always-trust test.txt
```

Just add either  **-yes** or  **-always-trust**.